Shiny.fluent is setting the default value not only on the start of the app
The default value should set only one time if the app is started not every time if the focus is on the pivot element.
Example : change the default value and click on another pivot element and go back. The written value in the text field is deleted. How to switch this off?
How can I switch this off?

Load the example
Change the default value
Go to the other Tab
Go back and see that your changes are gone

if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shiny.fluent)
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluentPage(
      div(
 Pivot(
          PivotItem(headerText = "aaaaaaa",
                    div(
                      #class = "directoryTextInput",
                      TextField.shinyInput(
                        inputId="inputIdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                        label = "label",
                        #type = "text",
                        description = "description",
                        value = "defaultValueaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                      ) )         
          ),
          PivotItem(headerText = "bbbbbb",
                    div(
                      #class = "directoryTextInput",
                      TextField.shinyInput(
                        inputId="inputIdbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
                        label = "label",
                        #type = "text",
                        description = "description",
                        value = "defaultValuebbbbbbbbbbbbb"
                      ) )         
          ) ) ) ),
 server = function(input, output) {}
  )
}

